# Trouble putting a table in a certain section

Tags: tables, sectioning, captions, tabularx

When I put the label at the bottom of my table, its title the section before the the section that it is currently in.
Here is my Preamble:

```
\documentclass[openany, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{grad_proseminar}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[page,titletoc,title]{appendix}
```

here is my code:

```
\chapter{Analysis \& Results}
\section{Software}
\section{Descriptive Statistics}
here is my table
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \scriptsize
   \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
   \begin{tabular}{|p{11em}|c|c|}
\hline
     \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Variable}} & \textbf{Frequency} & {\textbf{Percentage}} \\
 \end{tabular}%
     \end{adjustbox}
  \caption{Table 4.2}
   \end{table}%
```

The first section is software and the second is descriptive table. The table is showing as Table 4.1:Table 4.2 This table should be label as 4.2  or 4.2.1.

Comment: please merge bot code snippets in to one, complete document. from package in preamble keep only those relevant to your problem. label for citing table had to be always after `caption`.

Comment: `\caption` insertes `Table 4.1` for you. If you want to force it to be `Table 4.2`, just do `\stepcounter{table}` before the table.

Comment: Not related, but `hyperref` should be loaded last

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if I understand what the desired result is. So its only a guess.

The `book` class resets counter `table` by default when a new chapter starts. In the caption and in references the table number is shown as `<chapter>.<table>`. So if the table is the first one in chapter 4 it gets number 4.1.

If the table counter should be reset when a new section starts and the table number should include the section number, then add

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}% not needed for uptodate TeX distributions
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[openany, oneside]{book}
%\usepackage{grad_proseminar}% package is unknown
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}% not needed with an uptodate TeX distribution
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[page,titletoc,title]{appendix}

%\usepackage{chngcntr}% not needed for uptodate TeX distributions
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\usepackage{hyperref}% load as last package
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapter{Third chapter}
\chapter{Analysis \& Results}
\section{Software}
\section{Descriptive Statistics}
here is my table
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \scriptsize
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{11em}|c|c|}
    \hline
     \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Variable}} & \textbf{Frequency} & {\textbf{Percentage}} \\
  \end{tabular}%
   \end{adjustbox}
  \caption{Table 4.2}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]